# Why does openwhisk kubernetes pods status is pending in linux?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, openwhisk

I have implemented openwhisk using kubernetes in Windows operating system. The same thing I needs to implement in Linux. I followed following document to implement in Linux. [https://medium.com/@ansjin/openwhisk-deployment-on-a-kubernetes-cluster-7fd3fc2f3726](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). But when I try to get all pods details but openwhisk pods status is in pending only.

[image]

How to up these pods?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like something is going wrong with your Kubernetes/flannel installation. Kubernetes won't create new pods until it can assign the pod IPs properly, so the CNI that you use (in your case, flannel) needs to be working properly before OpenWhisk (or other applications) can be deployed.

If you investigate the flannel-ds pod with the CrashLoopBackOff and also try to figure out why the coredns pods haven't finished creating, that would be a good place to start debugging.